# ¿como puedo sacar de un array quienes an reprobado, quien buenas notas, etc? javascript y HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5, condiciones, while

mi problema consta en que el usuario introducirá en un input que longitud le quera dar al array, luego de tener el tamaño del array, en un `prompt` (ya con la longitud impuesta por el usuario anteriormente) el usuario introducirá numeros de notas, y el código me tiene que imprimir en un `</h1>` lo siguiente

1. Notas reprobadas (mayor que cero  y menor o igual que 6)
2. Notas buenas (mayor que 6 y menor o igual que 7)
3. Notas muy buenas (mayor que 7 y menor o igual que 9)
4. Notas Excelentes (mayor que 9 y menor o igual que 10)

como pudiese ir el código que separe los datos del array y los clasifique el los campos de: notas muy buenas, reprobados, notas buenas, etc.

mi código HTML es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Notas </title>
    <script src="work js/array.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="">cuantos array seran?</label>
        <input type="number" name="cantidad" placeholder="insertar numero de notas" class="form-group" >
        <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="capturarpika1()">
    </form>

    <h1>longitu de array es:</h1>
    <h1 id="cantidad"></h1>

    <h1>cuantos reprobaron</h1>
    <h1 id="reprobaron"></h1>

    <h1>Cuantas notas buenas</h1>
    <h1 id="buenas"></h1>

    <h1>cuantas notas muy buenas</h1>
    <h1 id="muybien"></h1>

    <h1>Cuantas notas exelentes</h1>
    <h1 id="exelent"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

y mi código javascript es este:

```
function capturarpika1(){
    var tamanio_array  =  parseInt(document.getElementsByName ('cantidad')[0].value);
    var array_notas = [tamanio_array];
    var sumar_notas = 0;
    var notas_muybuenas =0;
    var notas_exelentes =0;
    var x = 0;
    var notas_reprobadas=0;
    var notas_bueno=0;

while(x < tamanio_array){
var notas_generales = parseFloat(prompt('ingrese notas:' +  x))
array_notas[x] = notas_generales;
x++
}

x=0;

while(x < tamanio_array){
   if(array_notas ){

   }


}





document.getElementById('cantidad').innerHTML = array_notas;
document.getElementById('reprobaron').innerHTML = notas_reprobadas;
document.getElementById('buenas').innerHTML = notas_bueno;
document.getElementById('muybien').innerHTML = notas_muybuenas;
document.getElementById('exelent').innerHTML = notas_exelentes;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que la función javascript sigue el flujo mientras no encuentre ningún error, así que después de hacer todos los cálculos, solamente resta verificar que cumpla con los requisitos.

```
function capturarpika1(){
    var tamanio_array  =  parseInt(document.getElementsByName ('cantidad')[0].value);
    var array_notas = [tamanio_array];
    var sumar_notas = 0;
    var notas_muybuenas =0;
    var notas_exelentes =0;
    var x = 0;
    var notas_reprobadas=0;
    var notas_bueno=0;

while(x < tamanio_array){

var notas_generales = parseFloat(prompt('ingrese notas:' +  x));

array_notas[x] = notas_generales;

x++

}

//ingreso todas las notas, comparamos:

for (x=0; x < array_notas.length;x++){
    valor = array_notas[x]

    if (valor > 0 && valor < 7){
        notas_reprobadas +=1;
    }

    if (valor > 6 && valor < 8){
        notas_bueno +=1;
    }

    if (valor > 7 && valor < 10){
        notas_muybuenas +=1;
    }

    if (valor == 10){
        notas_exelentes +=1;
    } 

}

document.getElementById('cantidad').innerHTML = array_notas.length;
document.getElementById('reprobaron').innerHTML = notas_reprobadas;
document.getElementById('buenas').innerHTML = notas_bueno;
document.getElementById('muybien').innerHTML = notas_muybuenas;
document.getElementById('exelent').innerHTML = notas_exelentes;
}
```

Hazme saber cualquier duda.